# QML MouseArea Overlap other widget

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Here is some simple QML code which contains a `Button` and a `MouseArea`. I want the `Button` to detect both left and right mouse clicks.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill:parent;
    width: 1302
    height: 638

    Button {
        id: button1
        x: 378
        y: 332
        width: 194
        height: 66
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea1
        x: 368
        y: 306
        width: 226
        height: 108
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Click")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `MouseArea` is positioned on top of the `Button`, how can I force the `Button` to accept the mouse events?

Comment: You don't have any click handler in the `Button`. How do you get response? Don't use `anchors.fill` and `width`/`height` together. And use `z` if you really want to overlap one surface with another one. And as I know `Button` doesn't response to right mouse click. What exactly do you try to do here?

Comment: I want to popup a context menu when right-click on a button.

Comment: But more importantly, MouseArea get all the mouseEvent of other widget when we put on top of them (like tableView, textEditor.....) How can i fix it?

Comment: Hmm ... use `mouse.accepted=false` inside `MouseArea` events. But see the doc if event you use affected by `mouse.accepted`. For example, onClick doesn't affected by `mouse.accepted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if I understand you:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2


Window {
    id: screen
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Button")
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Button was clicked");
        }
        z: 100
        MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Button right button was clicked");
                    mouse.accepted = true
                }
            }
    }

    MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Window right button was clicked")
            }
            z: 99
        }
}
```

But I advice you to use common way to show button popup. Use `Button.menu` to show pull-down menu button.

Comment: oh wow O_O I have no idea how Z-Depth works in qml yet.
Will this work for repeater and delegate item too?

Comment: Can you take a look at my code please? I can't get the tableView's item selectable when put the mouseArea inside it.
https://gist.github.com/illunara/936367731e66db553ef0